# can ML learn concepts in an unsupervised manner

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning

I am wondering if ML can currently learn concepts in an unsupervised manner and how would that work.

For example, when it looks at a transaction, I would like ML to understand the concept of the matching principle which directs an organization to report an expense on its income statement in the same period as the related revenues.

Comment: Welcome to CV. As it stands, your question is quite broad and risks deletion. Assuming you're familiar with some of the literature on statistical and machine learning, would it be possible to more carefully specify your interests and concerns?

Answer (score 1):

Unsupervised learning can learn concepts. An example from Natural Language Processing is latent semantic indexing, where a set of documents are split into groups by content related concepts. However, the algorithm will discover the groups that it discovers. It is not easy to control it so that it finds the groups that you are targeting.

The example that you gave sounds as if it is deterministic, and possibly could be programmed with traditional procedural methods. However, if this is not the case and your data requires a pattern recognition methodology, this example still seems to be a binary classification problem, which is probably best addressed through supervised learning.